# Replace marked line with selected

Tags: vim

Is it possible to do the above?

I typically write all my software in the same way (omitting the TDD parts):

1. Iterate pseudo code until it is granular enough that each part can be written in, hopefully, under 20 minutes.
2. Implement each "pseudo"-component

Contrived example:

```
# Get file
# Open file
# Verify integrity
# Parse
# Close file
```

To encourage modularity i typically don't write these functions in "one" block. I write them in separate files or at least separate blocks and then "paste" them in. This is to ensure I'm not encouraged to add unnecessary dependencies. Right now, I'm literally copy->move to pseudocode-line->Paste over it with block of code, a function or method name, or whatever copy represents. This works very well for me and the code turns out nice. However, being lazy, I don't want to have to touch the mouse or do too much if there's a way to do it with less effort.
I'm looking for a way to select->copy->replace a pseudocode-line with the selected:

In file Parse.c:

```
int ParseMyFile(char* fileName)
{
  # Get file
  return 0;
}
```

I would then write # Get file in another file or buffer:

```
{GetFileSomehow}
```

As a next step I would love to just mark this block of code, and replace `# Get file`
with the block to produce:

```
int ParseMyFile(char* fileName)
{
  {GetFileSomehow}
  return 0;
}
```

I tried experimenting with marks to copy&paste "onto" a mark, but it did not work well enough. I copied->move to mark-> replace line. I would love to get this down to copy->replace.
I can not download extensions. I only have access to standard Vim.
It must be less effort than physically marking the block, navigate to the correct pseudo-line, and paste it. It may not sound like a lot of work, but I write even very small blocks of code like this, as little as 2-3 lines if it helps me reason about the code. It adds up.

Comment: There's the `:r` (`:read`) command to read a file's contents into the cursor position... Maybe that helps?

Comment: Consider using the [vi.se] Stack Exchange for questions on Vim.

Comment: Reposted in [vi.se] here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/28419/18609

Comment: Can't you just mark the line you want to replace with visual line mode (`shift+v`) and then past whatever you have copied with `p`?

Comment: That's precisely what I'm trying to avoid. That's what I'm currently doing. I want to mark what i want to copy in visual mode, and have it automatically pasted and replace a given label (e.g. implemented using marks).

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the text you want to replace in the clipboard you can do:

```
:.s/#.*/\=@+

.  ............. current line
#.*  ........... starting at this point
\=@+  .......... beloved vim replace using the clipboard
```

To jump back at onece we could do:

```
:%s/#.*/\=@+/ | exec "normal! \<c-o>"
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example? I have trouble seeing how this does not involve my cursor position or me actively having to write that line. Are you suggesting I write a macro / function with the mark as an argument?

Comment: Additional Note:  to paste from a vim register, change the '+' in '\=@+' to the register id. For example: ':s/#.*/\=@a'  to paste the contents of register 'a'.

Comment: To jump back you could use `Ctrl-o` [@gwow12345](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11930375/gwow12345)

Answer (score 0):

My try:

Once you have marked the line to replace (here in the example with mark `a`.
Select the text you want to copy there and enter:

```
:'<,'>y | norm!'aVp``
```

Of course the visual selection could be replaced by any other yank directive